# no error, but data not shown, stuck in processing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qp2W.jpg)
These are my files which is not showing my data in html only data is processing and no error also. I want to look my database through laravel in a html file but it's only processing and also not showing any error. so please help me on this error.

- no error, the ajax response is good, but data not shown and processing box keeps showing.
- Yajra 9.0
- Laravel 5.8

**MemberController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Member;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Datatables;
use Validator;

class MemberController extends Controller
{
public function addSocialMember(){
  return view("home.views.social-member");
}

public function listMember(){
  return view("home.views.memberlist");
}

public function listAllMember(){
  $memberlist = Member::query();
  return Datatables::of($memberlist)->make(true);
}

public function saveMember(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make(array(
      "name"=>$request->name,
      "email"=>$request->email,
      "phone"=>$request->phone,
      "state"=>$request->state,
      "city"=>$request->city,
      "issue"=>$request->issue,
      "message"=>$request->message,
    ),array(
      "name"=>"required",
      "email"=>"required|unique:member",
      "phone"=>"required",
      "state"=>"required",
      "city"=>"required",
      "issue"=>"required",
      "message"=>"required",
    ));

    if($validator->fails()){

      return redirect("social-member")->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }else{

      //successfully we have passed our form
      $member = new Member;
      $member->name = $request->name;
      $member->email = $request->email;
      $member->phone = $request->phone;
      $member->state = $request->state;
      $member->city = $request->city;
      $member->issue = $request->issue;
      $member->message = $request->message;

      $member->save();

      $request->session()->flash("message","Member has been submitted form successfully");

      return redirect("social-member");
    }
}
```

}

**Memberlist.blade.php**

```
 @extends("home.layouts.layout")

    @section("title","Social Member | Bheekho Foundation")

    @section("content")
    <div class="container padding-top-three">
    <br/>
      <blockquote><h4>We need  Help</h4></blockquote>
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="memberlist">
              <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Issue</th>
                <th>Describe Your Issues</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
              </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3./jquery.min.js"></script>
    @endsection
```

---

**web.php**

```
<?php

Route::get("/","HomeController@homepage");

 //Social Member Route
Route::get("/social-member","MemberController@addSocialMember")->name("addsocialmember");


Route::get("/memberlist","MemberController@listMember")->name("listmember");


Route::get("/memberlist-data","MemberController@listAllMember")->name("listallmember");


Route::post("/save-member","MemberController@saveMember")->name("savemember");
```

Comment: You're posting through ajax, but you are also doing session flashes and redirect returns in the action - they (at least to me) don't seem to mix well. How are you handling the response?

Comment: where is your loop for td? and maybe try dd(); the data you return

Comment: you can check out my attached image for more reference on this error.